# scripted new items don't show up in the "items" panel on Print Composer

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-2.12

I'm working on a plugin to put items (pictures, arrows, labels) on the Print Composer layout. Everything is fine with the exception that once they are drawn, none of these show up in the "items" panel until saving and reopening the project, or duplicating the composer (only in the duplicate). It is not a terrible problem but it is not ideal either. Does anyone know why and how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of a refresh method you need to call (composition.refreshItems())?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddling around I found out that after adding all the items, using the `QgsComposition.refreshZList()` function will do the trick. However, it is not possible to edit them from the "items" panel until saving and re-opening the project.